# Accessing a list inside a list through for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to iterate over a list (within a list) and I am having some trouble, any help would be appreciated.

```
boston <- data.frame(Boston)
# Subset 1:  zn - 2, chas-4, rm-6, dis-8, black-12, 
# Subset 2:  crim-1, indus-3, nox-5, age-7, tax-10, ptratio-11
# Subset 3: all
kvals <- c(1,3,5)
subset1 <- c("zn", "chas", "rm", "dis", "black")
subset2 <- c("crim", "indus", "nox", "age", "tax", "ptratio")
subset3 <- c(boston[,1:13])


x1.train <- boston[, c(subset1)]
x2.train <- boston[, c(subset2)]
x3.train <- boston[, 1:13]
y.train <- boston$medv01

xtrain.list <- list(x1.train, x2.train, x3.train)    

for (j in kvals ){
  message("~~~~ K = ", j, " ~~~~")
  for (s in xtrain.list ){
    knn.cv.pred <- knn.cv(xtrain.list[[s]], 
                          y.train,
                          k = kvals[j])

    message("Subset ", s, " K = ", j, " Error: ", mean(knn.cv.pred != y.train)*100, "%")
  }
  message("\n")
}
```

but i get this error

```
+ }
```

```
Error in xtrain.list[[s]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: Either use `s` instead of `xtrain.list[[s]]` or use `for (i in seq_along(xtrain.list)) { }`. You are treating `s` as a number, like "get the first value of `xtrain.list`", but in your current code `s` is actually the elements of that list. This is what the error means: you can't subset using a list object as the subscript (like `list(1, 2)[list(1)]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated with better reprex to call out appropriate libraries

In R you, one way to write a for loop is to use `seq_along` function inside the for loop.

```
boston <- data.frame(MASS::Boston)
# Subset 1:  zn - 2, chas-4, rm-6, dis-8, black-12, 
# Subset 2:  crim-1, indus-3, nox-5, age-7, tax-10, ptratio-11
# Subset 3: all
kvals <- c(1,3,5)
subset1 <- c("zn", "chas", "rm", "dis", "black")
subset2 <- c("crim", "indus", "nox", "age", "tax", "ptratio")
subset3 <- c(boston[,1:13])


x1.train <- boston[, c(subset1)]
x2.train <- boston[, c(subset2)]
x3.train <- boston[, 1:13]
y.train <- boston$medv

xtrain.list <- list(x1.train, x2.train, x3.train)    



for (k in seq_along(kvals) ){
  message("~~~~ K = ", k, " ~~~~")
  for (s in seq_along(xtrain.list) ){
    knn.cv.pred <- class::knn.cv(xtrain.list[[s]], 
                          y.train,
                          k = kvals[[k]])

    message("Subset ", s, " K = ", k, " Error: ", mean(knn.cv.pred != y.train)*100, "%")
  }
  message("\n")
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `for (k in kvals)`, so the `message` would actually display `k`. Then just change `kvals[[k]]` to `k` in the `knn.cv` call.